# Keybinding Service for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does anyone know of a service (or a person) that can translate a set of keybindings from editors like Sublime, Emacs, etc into their VS Code equivalent?

I'd love to be able to hand someone a list of keybindings that I'm used to from Sublime and not have to waste the time trying to learn what they're called in VS Code.

Paying someone, say, $50 to handle a dozen key bindings that would take me hours to do on my own would totally be worth it.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=VSCode&category=Keymaps&sortBy=Downloads

Comment: I've used a number of plug-ins however there are some command keybindings that I still can't figure out. For example, I'll pay anyone $10 right now if they know how to stop the "enter" key from going to the next result in the editor's finder window.

Comment: It's hard-coded.